# pdf viewer is not loading pdf file in safari browser

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

am unable to view pdf file using pdf.js in safari broswer and the viwer is working fine in chrome and mozilla ,when and trying to load pdf in safari its displaying error like

PDF.js v1.0.473 (build: 1694cd8)
Message: InvalidPDFException

how to solve this error?and am using safari 5.1.7 and i have included compatibility.js and used the below script but its not working in safari browser

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
 </script>
```

Comment: What is your OS? Does the file name contain special characters?

Comment: Can you provide more code?